# EC2 instance reach ability check fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an instance on aws, when I tried to start that instance it gives me error    EC2 reach ability check fail on "Instance Status Checks" I tried to troubleshoot with creating a new instance with same market place and in the same region and attached the volume but I am getting the same error on new instance after attaching the volume.

I have few backups on S3 is there any way to restore backups from S3 to ec2 instance.

and system logs showing following

```
 2.594228] List of all partitions:
[    2.599278] No filesystem could mount root, tried: 
[    2.606695] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    2.607685] CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 ve: 0 Not tainted 3.10.0-714.10.2.lve1.5.17.el7.x86_64 #1 29.2
[    2.607685] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 08/24/2006
```

Comment: Do you have an internet gateway in your VPC? Do your security groups and NACLs allow access? Your question doesn't have a lot of detail, it's difficult to help you. I've never seen anything about IPs on instance status checks - read about what they test [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html).

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the reply, I add log error in question if that makes some more sense!!

Comment: There's a problem with the disk. Create a new instance. If you need data off the old disk mount that disk as a volume to the new instance.